# Upload video from Xamarin app to azure blob store. Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a Xamarin app that contains a functionality to upload large videos to Azure Blob Storage.

Below is the code used.

```
BlobClientOptions blobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions();
blobClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient("ConnectionString", "ContainerName", "fileName", blobClientOptions);

//previewVideo is an array of bytes
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(previewVideo);

await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream);
```

Sometimes I am getting the below error.

```
Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry
(The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:01:40.
Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.)
```

As shown in the code above, I am setting the `NetworkTimeout` but it is always timing out after 100 seconds.

Comment: have you tried a value other than Infinite?

Comment: @jason yes I did, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/27953) on git hub, this was a know issue and it is solved last month in the last package update.

I updated the package and now the timeout property is working fine. Hence the problem is solved.